# HP Photosmart 6520 printer prints blue background

Tags: printing, hp

My HP Photosmart 6520 printer prints a blue background when it's printing colored. I put "hp-doctor" in my terminal end that's the result:
viktor78@viktor78:~$ hp-doctor

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.11)
Self Diagnose Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.11)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

-Gtk-Message: 20:12:55.653: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
\Gtk-Message: 20:12:55.704: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Checking for Deprecated items....
error: This distro (i.e ubuntu  18.04) is either deprecated or not yet supported.
The diagnosis is limited on unsupported platforms. Do you want to continue?(y=yes*, n=no):y

Checking for HPLIP updates....

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.11)
HPLIP upgrade latest version ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Latest version of HPLIP is already installed.

Checking for Dependencies....
warning: 12-18.04 version is not supported. Using 12-17.10 versions dependencies to verify and install...

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 GNU/Linux
 Host: viktor78
 Proc: 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 18.04
 Bitness: 64 bit

-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.17.11
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
warning: HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is not supported for 12 distro  18.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.17.11

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.17.11
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.17.11
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.17.11
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
qt5=no
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: File o directory non esistente

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1550864092
pending_upgrade_time = 0
latest_available_version = 3.17.10

[settings]
systray_visible = 0
systray_messages = 0

[last_used]
device_uri = "hp:/usb/Photosmart_6520_series?serial=TH472581TB05XP"
printer_name = 
working_dir = .

[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[refresh]
rate = 30
enable = false
type = 1

[polling]
enable = false
interval = 5
device_list = 

[fax]
voice_phone = 
email_address = 

[installation]
date_time = 23/02/2019 20:12:56
version = 3.17.11

 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               7.3.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.1             OK         -
 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.0           OK         -
 python-xml           Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.5           OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.7.3           OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 pil                  PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               1.1.7           OK         -
 pyqt4-dbus           PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         REQUIRED        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               2.27            OK         -
 python-devel         Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.15          OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.2.7           OK         -
 python-dbus          Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.6           OK         -
 cups-ddk             CUPS DDK - CUPS driver development kit                       OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 reportlab            Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.4.0           OK         -
 pyqt4                PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.2.7           OK         -
 python2X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.15          OK         -
 python-notify        Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.17.11         OK         -
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.17.11         OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.26            OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.27          OK         -
 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.2.7           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.19.4          OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
Gtk-Message: 20:13:30.848: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 20:13:30.880: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.2          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.17.11         OK         -
 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.17.11         OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/usb/Photosmart_6520_series?serial=TH472581TB05XP' is a Hewlett-Packard Photosmart_6520_series all-in-one
device `hpaio:/net/photosmart_6520_series?ip=192.168.1.101&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard photosmart_6520_series all-in-one

--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

  Device URI                        Model                    
  --------------------------------  -------------------------
  hp:/usb/Photosmart_6520_series?s  HP Photosmart 6520 series
  erial=TH472581TB05XP                                       

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

HP-Photosmart-6520-series
-------------------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/Photosmart_6520_series?serial=TH472581TB05XP
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP-Photosmart-6520-series.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP-Photosmart-6520-series.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: la stampante HP-Photosmart-6520-series è inattiva.  è stata abilitata da sab 23 feb 2019 20:07:15 CET
Communication status: Good

HP-Photosmart-6520-series-2
---------------------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/Photosmart_6520_series?serial=TH472581TB05XP
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP-Photosmart-6520-series-2.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP-Photosmart-6520-series-2.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: la stampante HP-Photosmart-6520-series-2 è inattiva.  è stata abilitata da dom 02 set 2018 18:04:00 CEST
Communication status: Good

--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

USB             HP-Photosmart-6520-series      Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/001/005' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'


Checking for Configured Queues....
warning: Fail to read ppd=/etc/cups/ppd/HP-Photosmart-6520-series.ppd file
warning: Insufficient permission to access file /etc/cups/ppd/HP-Photosmart-6520-series.ppd
warning: Could not complete Queue(s) configuration check

Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.

Diagnose completed...
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue on Linux Mint. It's most likely an issue with ghostscript.

A system update, including ghostscript. did solve the issue for me.

Hope this helps.